# How can i get all facebook friends who is not using my app or not login through my app

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk, android-facebook

Currently i am using facebook sdk 4.4 and i am want to fetch all the facebook friend list who is not uses my app.

I have written below code:

```
GraphRequestBatch batch = new GraphRequestBatch(
                        GraphRequest.newMyFriendsRequest(token,
                                new GraphRequest.GraphJSONArrayCallback() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onCompleted(JSONArray jsonArray,
                                                            GraphResponse response) {

                                        try {

                        //my code
                                            }

                                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }

                                    }
                                }), GraphRequest.newMeRequest(token,
                        new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {

                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(JSONObject object,
                                                    GraphResponse response) {
                                System.out.println("meJSONObject: "
                                        + object);

                                System.out.println("meGraphResponse: "
                                        + response);


                            }
                        }));
                batch.addCallback(new GraphRequestBatch.Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onBatchCompleted(GraphRequestBatch graphRequests) {
                        // Log.i(TAG, "onCompleted: graphRequests "+ graphRequests);
                    }
                });
                batch.executeAndWait();
```

From above code it is give my the list of friends who is using my app.

But i want the list of friends who is not using my app or not login through my app.

How can i do this?

Comment: i do not think facebook allows it

Comment: They are allows it. i have seen in many apps.

Comment: They don't. There is no way to get friends that are not using the app

Answer (score 0):

As of the new graph, it is only possible to get friends who also uses the app

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/user/friends

Comment: i want the friend list who is not using my app or i want all the friend list.

Comment: yes i have read and i have found other solution for this. i have  used              `"/me/taggable_friends"`.